# VK_MENU + VK_F[N} не посылает WM_SYSKEYDOWN

Tags: c++, winapi, input

Приветсвую.
Я столкнулся с проблемой при обработке клавиш в WinAPI. Проблема возникает сочетании Alt и клавиш F1, F2 и т.д. Т.е. я зажимаю F2, то всё ок. Вижу и нажатие и отжатие. Если зажимаю ALT + Q тоже ок:

```bash
INFO    WM_SYSKEYDOWN: key: 18
INFO    WM_SYSKEYDOWN: key: 81
INFO    WM_KEYUP: key: 18
INFO    WM_KEYUP: key: 81
```

А вот если зажимаю Alt + F1, то:

```bash
INFO    WM_SYSKEYDOWN: key: 18
INFO    WM_SYSKEYUP: key: 113
INFO    WM_KEYUP: key: 18
```

113 (VK_F2) нажалась, но не произошло события на отжатие. Почему? Тут даже prevent события через return не помогает. И проблема осталась. Почему-то только с F[N]
Проблему можно воспроизвести на любом WinAPI примере. Вот мой текущий код обработки клавиш:

```cpp
        LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
        {
            WindowPlatformData *window = (WindowPlatformData *)GetPropW(hwnd, L"MYWINDOW");
            switch (uMsg)
            { 
                case WM_SYSKEYUP:
                    logInfo("WM_SYSKEYUP: key: %d", wParam);
                    return TRUE;
                case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                    logInfo("WM_SYSKEYDOWN: key: %d", wParam);
                    return TRUE;
                case WM_KEYDOWN:
                    logInfo("WM_KEYDOWN: key: %d", wParam);
                    return TRUE;
                case WM_KEYUP:
                    logInfo("WM_KEYUP: key: %d", wParam);
                    return TRUE;
                case WM_CLOSE:
                    window->readyToClose = true;
                    break;
                case WM_DESTROY:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            }
            return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

Хочу понять в чём причина проблем. В документации Microsoft написано только про Alt + F10

Comment: ¿Клавиатура полноценная, без гостинга?

Comment: @user7860670 без понятия что такое гостинг. Обычная клавиатура. Сейчас проверяю с ноута. Мне кажется тут не физика. Больше похоже на какой-то софтварный резерв. Но нигде не могу найти инфы

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/applied-sciences/projects/anti-ghosting-demo/ У меня клавиатура без гостинга, описанной проблемы не наблюдаю

Comment: @user7860670 т.е. зажал ALT вместе с F2 и он показал 2?

Comment: Да, там показывает, какие клавиши зажаты. При отпускании в любом порядке они соответственно должны по одной пропадать из списка.

Comment: @user7860670 я подключил пару станционных клавиатур. В Demo F2 не бьётся. Если зажимаю ALT, то только ALT. F2 не определяется. Поэтому хочу уточнить. У тебя (или Вас - как удобней)  при зажатии ALT клавиша F2 регистрируется?

Comment: Да, у меня при зажатии Atl нажатие на F2 (и F1) правильно определяются. И события KEYUP всегда все приходят (я уже попробовал код из вопроса). Так что полагаю, что это у вас какая-то локальная проблема.

Comment: @user7860670 есть идеи что с этим делать? Ну кроме RID (RAW Input Device). Хочу понять причину

Comment: Если это проблема с клавиатурой, то RAW Input Device не поможет. Без замены клавиатуры наверное не обойтись.

Comment: @user7860670 у меня появилась идея что может быть после прочтения https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/inputdev/about-keyboard-input.md. К тому же проблема сразу на нескольких клавиатурах. При нажатии ALT включается режим перевода WM_KEY в WM_SYSKEY после нажатия происходит обработка системного сообщения которая идёт вне контекста текущего WndProc. В результате на DOWN событие не приходит. Просто видимо клавиши F являются тригером для этого. Если я прав, RID поможет т.к. не првязаны к конкретному дескриптору. Что думаешь?

Comment: Я уже написал, что думаю, что проблема в клавиатуре. У меня эта проблема не воспроизводится, никакие сообщения не пропадают.